# Empties are not transforming

Tags: camera, transforms, lighting, shortcut, coordinates

[image: Empties Physically and transformer at different locations]

I was following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K02hlKyoWNI&t=495s for camera to path.
There was a shorcut Alt+G to centre and object. Since I did the same there was some disconnect between the empties on screen and their co ordinates. As in image the camera empties is visually at the centre but the camera frame is at the co-ordinates.

Same is for the light. It physically appears at centre while it's co ordinates are different.
[image: Light Empty is at centre but physical location is different.]

The same goes for any future empty I create. It is very annoying.
I have tried Blender reset and Re install but nothing is making this go away.
Please help resolve it.

[image]

Comment: At first glance this seems really weird. It seems you can move the origin of a camera (or a light) away form the visible representation of that thing. I believe that is not supposed to be happening. Though its hard to tell for sure, or anything else, without the .blend file. You might want to consider uploading it. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: When I open the file in the same version of Blender, the visual representation of the camera and the light are at their respective origins. If this is in fact not the case for you, I'd say you could call this a bug and proceed accordingly. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports

Comment: Thanks, I will report the bug. I reinstalled but the error still remains, position says one while visually they are at different place.

Comment: I uploaded the bug report.

Answer (score 1):

The Bug team resolved it. Apparently the Viewport was not updating.
I had to install the new graphics card drivers and it started working fine.

Comment: Great! I feel a bit foolish for not suspecting and advising it myself, but good to hear you got it resolved. : )