# Why is selected item highlighted in Red?

Tags: transforms

I am new to Blender. I watched a few tutorials for Blender and I noticed that their selected objects are highlighted yellow.
I try to copy the tutorials. I have only ONE object and I want to move that ONE object.
When I select that ONE object it is highlighted in red. Wow, that is completely unexpected! I can't move or rotate the object. I want so desperately to do something as basic as moving an object. I suspect that the object does not move because it is red. I am so mad. Why is the selected object highlighted red?

[image]
The result of moving the cube the tutorial way.

[image: No "Transform Affect Only" has been selected]
No "Transform Affect Only" has been selected

[image]
Clicking on the yellow dot in the bottom left corner will highlight the cube red and clicking on the cube will do nothing.

Comment: Can you click on it (click - not box/drag select) in the **3d view**?

Comment: The yellow dot will move.

Comment: The Origin dot moves but the mesh does not move with it even though the Affect Only Origins box for Transform is not checked? It might be related to this problem (if so it might be fixed if you update your video card drivers) https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/184558/empties-are-not-transforming?noredirect=1#comment309438_184558 If you have the same problem you can move the Origin away from camera's and lights, which should not happen.

Comment: I updated drivers and the select box has changed from red to orange. Thanks.